# Scala type inference breaking down in obvious setting?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I have a rather simple piece of code that does not compile, as a type can apparently not be inferred. I would like to understand why it does not, as I have plenty of type annotations, and it should work. The code is

```
object MyApp {

  trait A { 
    type V
    val value: V
  }

  case class ConcreteA(value: Int) extends A { type V=Int }

  def convert[T<:A](v: T#V): T = ConcreteA(v.asInstanceOf[Int]).asInstanceOf[T] // brief method with casts for illustration purposes only


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val i: Int = 10
    val converted: ConcreteA = convert(i)
  }

}
```

(It compiles if I add an explicit `[ConcreteA]` on the `convert`-call)

The error I get is

```
MyApp.scala:19: error: no type parameters for method convert: (v: T#V)T exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Int)
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Int
 required: ?T#V
    val converted: ConcreteA = convert(i)
                               ^
MyApp.scala:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: T#V
    val converted: ConcreteA = convert(i)
                                       ^
MyApp.scala:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : T
 required: MyApp.ConcreteA
    val converted: ConcreteA = convert(i)
                                      ^
three errors found
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Edit: I expected Scala to deduce that `T` is `ConcreteA` here. I did so because the result of the `convert` call goes into a val type annotated as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, *as far as I know*, is that type inference works using the [**Unification algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)), which simply will try to satisfy the constraints for the given values. It will first try to prove that the input `v` satisfy the type `T#V`, but at this moment, it does not have any information about `T` thus it simply fails before checking if the result type satisfy the condition.
If you explicitly specify that `T` is `ConcreteA` then it will be able to continue.

However, you can make it work by postponing the type checking of the arguments after the inference, using [**Generalized Type Constraints**](https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html).

```
def convert[T <: A, V](v: V)(implicit ev: V <:< T#V): T = ???

val converted: ConcreteA = convert(10)
// converted: ConcreteA = ConcreteA(10)

val converted: ConcreteA = convert("hey")
// Compile error:  Cannot prove that String <:< T#V.
```

In this case the value `v` does not have any restrictions, thus the compiler simple bind `V` to the type of `v` which it already knows what it is. Then, it checks the return type `T` which it knows must be a `ConcreteA`, which satisfy the constraint that it must be a subtype of `A`, thus it pass.
After having solved the inference, the compiler attempts to solve the **implicits**. In this case, it needs to obtain *(prove)* that `V <:< T#V`, which in the first case works, but in the second fails.

Comment: While this is a valid workaround it doesn't answer the question—the OP repeatedly asks for an an explanation of what they're seeing.

Comment: @TravisBrown you are absolutely correct, my mistake. I have just edited the answer... however, I am not as versed in the compiler and type systems in general as I would want. I know you surely are way better than me, if you could check that the answer is correct I would really appreciate it, thanks in advance.